# Why am I failing to calculate the Bohr radius correctly?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, units, hydrogen

This is the formula that I'm using:

$$r_n=\frac{h^2}{4\pi^2me^2}\times\frac{n^2}{Z}$$

Here,

$r_n$ = radius of nth orbit

$h$ = Planck's constant $(6.626\times10^{-34}Js)$

$m$ = mass of an electron $(9.1\times10^{-31}kg)$

$e$ = charge of a proton $(1.6\times10^{-19}C)$

$n$ = principal quantum number ($n=1$ in our case)

$Z$ = atomic number

**My attempt:**

$$r_1=\frac{(6.626\times10^{-34})^2}{4\pi^2\times9.1\times10^{-31}\times(1.6\times10^{-19})^2}\times\frac{1}{1}$$

$$=0.477m\ (\text{approx})$$

But this is the wrong answer! The correct Bohr radius is $0.0529\times10^{-9}m$

**Question:**

1. Why am I getting the wrong answer? What mistake am I making?

Comment: Your formula misses a factor $4\pi\epsilon_0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius

Comment: @ThomasFritsch If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer to my question. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula misses a factor $4\pi\epsilon_0$.
According to [Wikipedia - Bohr radius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius)
the correct formula is
$$r_n=\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0h^2}{4\pi^2me^2}\times\frac{n^2}{Z}$$

Answer (score -1):

Your mathematical calculation is correct, but your formula is not correct and you didn't take into account the reduced mass of proton - electron see [StackExchange answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/497409/derivation-using-reduced-mass-for-electron-orbitals-in-the-bohr-model) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius).